# hasMany and belongs issue when upgraded from ember-data version 4 to 8

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a Item has many Things and Thing belongTo Item association.

I can do item.get("things")

But when i try and so the reverse thing.get("item") i get null !

Does this work differently now in version from 5 onwards ?    Is there something else / new i need to do ?   Does anyone know of a bug ?

I have setup the mappings and am getting no errors

Please help.

thanks a lot
Rick

Comment: Hey Rick, what does the JSON look like that you're giving Ember Data?